# Having TinyMCE's HTML editor come up in a tab and not a popup window?

Tags: html, wordpress, editor, popup, tinymce

We have the default TinyMCE installation where clicking on the button to bring up the HTML editor makes it come up in a popup window. With something like Wordpress, the HTML editor is just another tab inside the TinyMCE box, which is a nicer alternative.

Is it possible to setup TinyMCE so the HTML editor just comes up in another tab of some sort inside TinyMCE box itself, rather than a popup window? (ala Wordpress)

Thank you